# Why isn't the border value called thickness?

Tags: css, border

One of the values the border property can accept in CSS is called width, but I believe this is misleading and is an improper naming convention. Here's the definition of width:

> Width: the measurement or extent of something from side to side.

This makes absolutely no sense because you can specify border-top-width and border-bottom-width; this would qualify the measurement as height, not width.

> Height: The measurement from base to top.

Is there a reason the border value isn't named thickness instead? This would be an accurate naming convention.

Comment: Seems like the spec agrees with you http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-width. It is referred to as `line thickness`, it's just the property that's called `border-width`.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider every aspect. Because it should be a light-weight and internatinal language, `width` is more readable and memorizable than `thickness`. It's just about being easy to use and read

Comment: Can you explain to me how `width` is more memorable than `thickness`? I run a memory camp and there really isn't a distinction from my point of view. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Aside from the word having more characters. Is that a sacrifice we should make to not have accurate naming conventions?

Comment: Im from Iran. I speak Persian. Lets think that I'm not good in english. So this way, I'd rather the word be shorter. The other thing is that its faster in typing. Anyway I'm not sure about this.

Comment: I think a programming language should always be as clear as possible and I hear your concern (I speak multiple languages myself). But unfortunately, I cannot accept this as an answer.